# Two Search bars are appearing when I run my app but only one shows on storyboard

Tags: swift, xcode, uisearchbar

I am currently building a table view and I noticed that after my table view is populated I am getting two search bar fields. My original intention was to have only one search bar field appear (shown on my interface) I can't seem to figure out what this happens. When I try to delete the search bar from my interface then my table view will not load and populate data.

Here is a screenshot of the interface storyboard:

[image: Single Search bar]

Here is the screenshot of when I run the app:

[image: Double Search Bars]

Here is some code including my viewDidLoad:
**EDIT**: Added TableView Code

```swift
class AddHarvestPlanViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var AddHarvestPlanPluCodeTable: UITableView!

    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        findPluCodeParents(searchTextField: "apple")
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Find your Commodity"
        navigationItem.searchController = searchController
        definesPresentationContext = true

        AddHarvestPlanPluCodeTable.delegate = self
        AddHarvestPlanPluCodeTable.dataSource = self
        AddHarvestPlanPluCodeTable.reloadData()

    }
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        var count = harvestCommodities.count
        return count
    }
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AddPluCodeCustomCell", for: indexPath) as! AddPluCodeCustomCell
        do{
            let item = harvestCommodities[indexPath.row]
            cell.commodity?.text = item.plu_code_commodity
            cell.package?.text = "Cases"
            return cell
        }
    }
func findPluCodeParents(searchTextField:String){
        let searchText =  searchTextField


        print("Searching for....",searchTextField)
        let aggriEndpoint: String = "https://xxxx.xxxx.com/xxxx/xxxxx"

        let url = URL(string:aggriEndpoint)
        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url:url!)
        urlRequest.httpMethod = "GET"

        let session = URLSession.shared
        print("running task")
        let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest, completionHandler: {data,response,error -> Void in
            do{
                print("All finiished")
                print(data)
                if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [[String:Any?]]{
                    //                print(json)
                    for item in json{
                        print(item as? [String:Any?])

                        var active = item["active"] as? Bool
                        let cases_per_week  = (item["cases_per_week"] as! NSString).doubleValue
                        var cases_per_palette  = item["cases_per_pallette"] as? Int
                        var lbs_per_week = (item["lbs_per_week"] as! NSString).doubleValue
                        var cases_per_week_avg = item["cases_per_week_avg"] as? Int
                        var pounds_per_case = item["pounds_per_case"] as? Int
                        var repeat_harvest = item["repeat_harvest"] as? Bool
                        var harvest_week_count = item["harvest_week_count"] as? Int
                        var plant_days = item["plant_days"] as? Int
                        var pounds_per_acre = item["pounds_per_acre"] as? Int
                        var options = item["options"] as? Int
                        var plu_code_variety = item["plu_code_variety"] as? String
                        var plu_code_commodity = item["plu_code_commodity"] as? String
                        var id = item["id"] as? Int
                        var plu_code = item["plu_code"] as? Int
                        var acres = item["acres"] as? Int

                        self.harvestCommodities.append(PluCode(id: id!, commodity: plu_code_commodity!, cases_per_week_avg: cases_per_week_avg!, repeat_harvest: repeat_harvest!, cases_per_week: cases_per_week, lbs_per_week: lbs_per_week, acres: acres!, plu_code: plu_code!, active: active!, options: options!, plant_days: plant_days!, plu_code_commodity: plu_code_commodity!, plu_code_variety: plu_code_variety!, cases_per_palette: cases_per_palette!, harvest_week_count: harvest_week_count!, pounds_per_acre: pounds_per_acre!))
                    }
                }

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.AddHarvestPlanPluCodeTable.reloadData()
                }

            } catch let error{
                print("error")
            }
        })

        task.resume()

    }
```

Comment: When I delete it my tableview doesn't populate @Sweeper

Comment: "When I try to delete the searchbar from my interface then my tableview will not load and populate data" Is there an error? If so what is the message? Can you show the code that populates the data as well?

Comment: @Sweeper I don't get any error codes. I added my tableview codes. I feel like the issue might not be there since It populates fine with I have the search bar?

Comment: Why do you add it via stroyboard while you added it from the code?

Comment: @Maysam That is a great point. Problem solved! Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either remove the code where you create the upper Search Bar, ("let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)") and then connect an IBOutlet to the one you have created on the interface to your swift file, or remove the one on the storyboard and use the one you have created in your code, and connect the results to your table view